# Why is one page slightly differently aligned to another?

Tags: html, css, mediawiki

Hey can someone help me out here, my Home page is aligned differently to all the other pages... Not a big deal but would like to know why.

Home: http://2013hs.igem.org/Team:St_Pauls_London

Other: http://2013hs.igem.org/Team:St_Pauls_London/Project

Thanks :D

Comment: I'm guessing your screen is adding a scrollbar for one, since the height is slightly larger.  They both look the same for me.

Comment: Are you referring to `justification` of text?

Answer (score 1):

Add overflow:hidden seems to fix when added to the body of the other pages

Answer (score 0):

Your homepage also has content in an additional div that isn't present on the other page. That div is set to justify the text and margin-right.